# Is this answer wrong? Shouldn't it be $+8x$ in numerator? (it's in my textbook)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I did it with log and quotient rule and got $+8x$ in numerator both times.
Am I making a mistake or is the answer is wrong?

[image: logarithmic_differentiation_calculation]

Comment: Yes it should be +8x.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks @AnkitKumar

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to learn MathJax.

Comment: Hmm,   sure seems wrong to  me.  Let's see. If $x > 2$ then if we compare $y(x)$ to $y(x + h); h> 0$ we know $$y(x+h) > y(x) \iff \frac {(x+h)^2 - 4}{(x+h)^2 + 4} > \frac {x^2 -4}{x^2 + 4} \iff ((x+h)^2 -4)(x^2+4) > (x^2 -4)((x+h)^2 +4) \iff -4x^2 + 4(x+h)^2 > -4(x^2 +h)^2 + 4x \iff 8(x+h)^2 > 8x^2\iff x+h > x$$ which of course it is.  So at $x> 2$, $y$ is increasing so $y'$ is positive.  Which is not what the book gets.  So the book is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the third to last line the book calculates $(x^3 + 4x) - (x^3 - 4x) = -8x$.

Well.... obviously that is a careless error. (One that we've *all* made and will all make again sometime).

So you are right and the book is wrong.

This may be overkill but $x > 2$ then book's derivative is negative and ours is positive.  So for $2 < x < x'$ we can check to see if $y$ increases or decreases.

I claim for positive $b > a > c$ that $\frac {b-c}{b+c} > \frac {a-c}{a+c} \iff (b-c)(a+c) > (b+c)(a-c) \iff bc - ac > ac - bc $ which is clearly true as $bc - ac > 0 > ac - bc$.

So $\sqrt{\frac {x'^2 -4}{x'^2 + 4}} > \sqrt{\frac {x^2 -4}{x^2 +4}}$ and $y$ is increasing which confirms our suspicions and refutes the book's result.